# Convolution of two chi square independent random variables

Tags: statistics

How do you use the convolution formula in order to prove that the sum of two chi square random variables with degrees of freedom m and n respectively results in a chi square distribution? Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Im struggling to actually start the question, the convolution formula itself I don’t really understand

Comment: @Lauracharle : Notice that if $X,Y$ are independent DISCRETE random variables whose values are nonnegative integers $0,1,2,3,\ldots,$ then $$ \begin{align} &  \Pr(X+Y=3) \\ {} \\ = {} & \Pr\Big( \big( X=0\ \&\ Y=3\big) \text{ or } \big( X=1\ \&\ Y=2\big) \\ & {} \qquad \text{ or } \big( X=2\ \&\ Y=1\big) \text{ or } \big(X=3\ \&\ Y=0\big)\Big) \\ {} \\ = {} & \sum_{k=0}^3 \Pr(X=k)\Pr(Y=3-k) \end{align} $$ There you have a convolution, evaluated at $3,$ of the distributions of $X$ and $Y.$ Does that answer any of your concerns about the nature of convolution? $\qquad$

Comment: @Lauracharle : There was an error in an important detail in my answer. I've fixed it. The idea remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If just getting the bottom-line conclusion is the purpose, then there are quicker ways than computing the convolution of density functions, but I take it the question is precisely about finding the convolution.

The chi-square distribution with $j$ degrees of freedom is
$$
f_j(x)\,dx = \frac 1 {\Gamma(j/2)} \left( \frac x 2\right)^{j/2-1} e^{-x/2} \left( \frac{dx} 2 \right) \text{ for } x\ge0.
$$
And then:
\begin{align}
& (f_j*f_k)(x) \\[8pt] = {} & \int_0^x f_j(u)f_k(x-u) \, du \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {\Gamma(j/2)\Gamma(k/2)} \int_0^x \left( \frac u 2 \right)^{j/2-1} \left( \frac{x-u} 2 \right)^{k/2-1} e^{-x/2} \, \frac{du} 4
\end{align}
Here you see that $e^{-u/2} \cdot e^{-(x-u)/2}$ became $e^{-x/2},$ and that quantity does not change as $u$ goes from $0$ to $x,$ so we can pull it out, thus:
$$
\frac {e^{-x/2}} {\Gamma(j/2)\Gamma(k/2)} \cdot\frac 1 {2^{(j+k)/2}} \int_0^x u^{j/2-1} (x-u)^{k/2-1} \, du \tag 1
$$
Now a simple substitution:
\begin{align}
v & = u/x \\
dv & = du/x
\end{align}
As $u$ goes from $0$ to $x,$ so $v$ goes from $0$ to $1.$

The expression on line $(1)$ above becomes
\begin{align}
& \frac {e^{-x/2}} {\Gamma(j/2)\Gamma(k/2)} \cdot \frac 1 {2^{(j+k)/2}} \int_0^1 \big( xv \big)^{j/2-1} \big( x(1-v) \big)^{k/2-1} \, \big(x\,dv\big) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac {e^{-x/2} } {\Gamma(j/2)\Gamma(k/2)} \cdot \left( \frac x 2 \right)^{(j+k)/2-1} \cdot \frac 1 2 \underbrace{\int_0^1 v^{j/2-1} (1-v)^{k/2-1} \, dv}_\text{No “$x$'' appears here!}
\end{align}

I'll leave the remaining details to you.

(This also illustrates why the gamma function should be defined by $$ \Gamma(\alpha) = \text{an expression in which $(\alpha-1)$ appears.} $$ The reason is that, as you see above, where $j$ and $k$ occurred in the two factors, we now have $j+k$ in the result.)